# View of most recent nodes, one per taxonomy term selected

Tags: views, 6

Drupal 6 Views 2.x

I am looking to create a view that lists the most recent node from a selected list of taxonomy terms.  However, I only want it to display the most recent item from EACH term.

So if I select term 1, term 3, and term 7 it will list the most recent node that was tagged with that term, grouped and distinct.

Something like this:

Term 1:
Title
Body

Term 3:
Title
Body

Term 7:
Title
Body

Is this possible to do with a single view? I would prefer it to be one view instead of creating a bunch of different views that return 1 item per category which would be possible.  The other thing I am hoping it would do  is if a node is tagged with both term 1 and term 3, it would only show up once, ie on term 1, and then when it gets to term 3, it would select the next most recent node since the most recent one was already displayed.